# Group policy for accessing sound settings

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

On a customer site, a "normal" (i.e. non-administrative) user cannot access the sound settings (mmsys.cpl) of the computer, whereas an admin can. From the error message the user receives, my impression was that a group policy causes the problem. Do you know which group policy can do so (the customer's admins do not know that...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run gpresult /v from an administrator level command line on the computer that is having the issue.  This will show which group policies are being applied and, from there, you'll know which policy's settings to inspect.

Comment: [rsop.msc](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010(v=ws.10).aspx) (which I believe is an optional download for XP but is present in more recent client systems out of the box) gives a nice GUI with expandable nodes and ADM text explanations for current policy settings.

Comment: The rsop.msc suggestion is very good, I could try that program on my local computer where grpresult /v does not work. I could not yet check at the customer site.

Answer (score 1):

Check:

```
ControlPanelDisplay.admx    
User
Prevent changing sounds
```

A helpful resource are the Group policy object spreadsheets, which document settings by platform. You can find them on the [Microsoft download site.](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25250)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Group policy spreadsheets. According to them, the policy you suggested is not available on Server 2008 (not an R2). I could not yet check on the customer site.